# What causes the problem when compiling a displayed equation with \overbrace and \underbrace?

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath

```
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
m+n\\
m
\end{array}
\right)
= \frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}
= \frac{\overbrace{(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots(n+1)}^\mbox{$m$ factors}}{\underbrace{m(m-1)\cdots 1}_\mbox{$m$ factors}}
$$
```

I am getting an error and cannot figure out the cause.

Comment: Next time, please also post the content of the error.  And if you can include the `documentclass` etc that make this into a MWE, that would be even better.

Comment: Since the answers don't tell: `^\mbox{...}` and `_\mbox{...}` are the problems. Better: `^{\mbox{...}}`. Even better: `^{\text{...}}`.  (Also please have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use `\[ \]` instead `$$ $$` for display math formulas. Like @WillieWong say, with `amsmath` package You can get a result, perhaps, more appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \binom{m+n}{m}
     = \frac{(m+n)!}{m!\,n!}
     = \frac{\overbrace{(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots(n+1)}^{m \text{ factors}}}{\underbrace{m(m-1)\cdots 1}_{m \text{ factors}}}
  \]
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `^{\text{$m$ factors}}` is better

Comment: I see, can you explain me, why `^{\text{$m$ factors}}` is better?

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
m+n\\
m
\end{array}
\right)
= \frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}
= \frac{\overbrace{(m+n)(m+n-1)\cdots(n+1)}^{\mbox{$m$ factors}}}{\underbrace{m(m-1)\cdots 1}_{\mbox{$m$ factors}}}
$$
\end{document}
```

The `^\mbox{$m$ factors}` was changed to `^{\mbox{$m$ factors}}` in two cases (one for superscript and another for subscript), which should be grouped using curly braces.

Comment: If one is using `amsmath`, one might as well use `\binom` instead of doing it by hand in the left hand side. It may also make sense using `\text` instead of `\mbox`.

Comment: @WillieWong: I do agree with you regarding the use of `\text` instead of `\mbox`.