# How to ignore the size of the content when using underbrace and overbrace?

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

Based on the suggestion here [How to add an underbrace and overbrace to a term in a equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343422/how-to-add-an-underbrace-and-overbrace-to-a-term-in-a-equation) or here [What causes the problem when compiling a displayed equation with \overbrace and \underbrace?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319862/what-causes-the-problem-when-compiling-a-displayed-equation-with-overbrace-and) for instance, is it possible we have a "small" and the same size the symbols for underbrace and overbrace together?

I was trying to use the code below. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[
\begingroup
\color{red}\underbrace{\overbrace{\color{black}=}^{\mathrm{over over over over over}}}_{\mathrm{under}}
\endgroup
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the full code that you use, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano, I put a MWE above. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `\mathclap` (`mathtools` package) allows the horizontal width of the content to be ignored.

In the 2nd example, arising from an OP comment, I use `stackengine` to reverse the sense of the braces.  There, I also use `\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}` to ignore the width of the
over/under text relative to the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\stackMath
\begin{document}

\[
\begingroup
\color{red}
\underbrace{\overbrace{\color{black}=}^{\mathclap{%
\mathrm{over over over over over}}}}_{\mathrm{under}}
\endgroup
\]
\[
x
\mathrel{
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackunder{\stackon{=}{\color{red}\underbrace{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{
  over over over over over}}}}{\color{red}\overbrace{\scriptscriptstyle
  \mathrm{under}}}
}
y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just by the challenge, is it possible to invert the position symbols?

Comment: @Moura Do you mean for the braces to embrace the word, rather than the equal sign?

Comment: Your code is perfect. But if we'll use, for example in the code below, the braces get space of integer symbol. 
\[ \int 2x\sqrt{x^2+1}\ dx
  \mathrel{
   \renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
   \stackunder{\stackon{=}{\color{red}\underbrace{\text{$u=x^2+1$}}}}{\color{red}\overbrace{
     \text{$du=2xdx$}}}
  }
  \int \sqrt{u}\ du\]

Comment: @Moura Both `\stackunder` and `\stackon` take an optional argument that, in this case, denotes the separation gap between stacked elements.  So change `\stackunder` to `\stackunder[8pt]` and likewise for `\stackon`.